# Single bit transfer from Arduino to RPi through gpio

Tags: gpio, arduino

Trying to send commands from an Arduino to the RPi through the GPIO PCM. I can't do it through the serial port as the port is connected to a computer and commanding the Arduino. I was planning to send single hex codes (0011,1010,1101,etc), through the GPIO but it doesn't appear to be working as intended. I wrote the following code in the Arduino to send the signal.

```
const int RPiPins[3][3] = {{1,2,4},
                           {2,5,6},
                           {3,7,8}
                          };

/* Define input pins from the RPI Army */
const int RPiInPins[3][3] = {{1,A0,A1},
                             {2,A2,A3},
                             {3,A4,A5}
                            };

int ComControlValue = -1; // switch control
int signalDelay = 10; // delay for output

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);           // Set serial port to receive input

  /* Set pins to output*/
  pinMode(RPiPins[0][1],OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(RPiPins[0][2],OUTPUT);   
  pinMode(RPiPins[1][1],OUTPUT);        
  pinMode(RPiPins[1][2],OUTPUT);         
  pinMode(RPiPins[2][1],OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RPiPins[2][2],OUTPUT);   
  /* Make sure all pins are set to 0 volts*/
  CallPins(0,0,0);   
  CallPins(1,0,0);  
  CallPins(2,0,0);
}

void loop() {
  switch(ComControlValue){
    case -1:
       Serial.println("Waiting for Command");
       while (Serial.available()==0){}
       ComControlValue=Serial.parseInt();
       break;     
    case 1:
       InputRequest();
       SendBinaryInput(1010);   // Sending  Input To RPi
       ComControlValue= -1; 
       break;
  }
}

void SendBinaryInput(int args) {
    int counter = 3;
    int I1;
    int ii;
    int PinsOut;

    while (counter > -1) {
      I1 = args / (int)pow(10,counter) % 10 ;                                  
    // Pulls out the digits individually
      delay(signalDelay);

      if (I1 == 1) {
        CallPins(0,1,1);
        CallPins(1,1,1);
        CallPins(2,1,1);
        counter--;
      }
      else if (I1 == 0) {
        CallPins(0,0,1);
        CallPins(1,0,1);
        CallPins(2,0,1);
       counter--;
      }
    delay(signalDelay);
    CallPins(0,0,0);
    CallPins(1,0,0);
    CallPins(2,0,0);
    delay(signalDelay);
  }
}

/* Simple function for calling Pins based on RPi */
void CallPins(int args,int PinA, int PinB) {
   digitalWrite(RPiPins[args][1],PinA);
   digitalWrite(RPiPins[args][2],PinB); 
}

void InputRequest(){
    CallPins(0,1,1);
    CallPins(1,1,1);
    CallPins(2,1,1);
    delay(signalDelay*2);
    CallPins(0,0,0);
    CallPins(1,0,0);
    CallPins(2,0,0);
    delay(signalDelay*2);
}
```

code is a bit long. I pretty much setup so the output from the Arduino is 2 pins (for 1) or 1 pin (for 0). I even have delays set to allow for the RPi to receive the command. The code works well when I attach the output pins to LEDS.

As for the RPi, Here is the code I wrote to receive the inputs. The code I wrote though is in Python which might be part of the problem.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from RPi.GPIO import LOW, OUT, HIGH, BCM
from threading import Thread
import time

Listen = True        # Value for loop to run
ComArd = [0,0,0,0]       # Command from Arduino to Follow
OutPins = [22,27]
InPins = [6, 12]

GPIO.setmode(BCM)        # Set GPIO to BCM pin layout
GPIO.setup(InPins[0],IN)
GPIO.setup(InPins[1],IN)

def Listening(Listen):
    while Listen:
        if GPIO.input(InPins[0]) and GPIO.input(InPins[1]):
            ComArd = RetrieveCommand()
            print(ComArd)
        elif GPIO.input(InPins[0]) and not GPIO.input(InPins[1]):
            pass
        elif GPIO.input(InPins[1]) and not GPIO.input(InPins[0]):
            pass
def RetrieveCommand():
    EventListen = True         # For loop to receive input
    BinColl = 0
    while EventListen:
        if GPIO.input(InPins[0]) and not GPIO.input(InPins[1]):
            ComArd[BinColl] = 0
            BinColl = BinColl + 1
            time.sleep(0.01)
        elif GPIO.input(InPins[1]) and GPIO.input(InPins[0]):
        ComArd[BinColl] = 1
        BinColl = BinColl + 1
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if BinColl == 3:
            EventListen = False
    EventListen = True
    return ComArd
```

Comment: Can you send a serial data bit stream at something like 19k2 baud?  If so you could use [pigio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) to receive the data.  Try `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs slro 23 19200 8` where 23 is the GPIO to use and 8 is the bits per byte.  Then send some data and try `pigs slr 23 100` where 23 is the GPIO and 100 means read up to a 100 bytes.  If that works you can do the same in C and Python.

Comment: I think it would be fine. I want to send a 4 or 8 bit code to notify the RPi to run function X or Y.

Comment: I meant to say I didn't look at your current code but in principal the idea behind it should work.

Comment: Why not simply use either the I2C or SPI busses to send the bytes across?

Comment: Having abandoned the Arduino for the Raspberry Pi myself, I am really curious about your application. What is the Arduino doing? My Pi does I2C, W1, closes relays, etc.

Comment: So I'm trying to have the Arduino communicate with 3 raspberry pi's. I want them to monitor something at the same time. The Arduino is also controlling a motor shield to control separate step motors. As I needed the motor shield to control the motors. I thought it would be good as well to have the arduino notify the RPi to start watching.

Comment: I need the ability to pass bits as I only have 2 input pins connected to each Pi and at least 6 different functions to perform. I thought about sending different number of pulses but I was worried it might not be optimal or reliable. I decided that a 2 pin setup and sending small binary codes would be best as it gave room for expansion in case I needed more codes to perform certain functions.

Comment: What Arduino are you using and at what voltage?  Hopefully not a 5v model......

Comment: I'm using the Arduino Uno with the adafruit motor shield. sadly it is a 5v model so I am using resistors to decrease the voltage to the RPi.

Comment: After reading through posts and forums. It appears that the I2C method might be the best option for setting up the type of connections I want. thanks for the input.